# My cursor keeps on jumping while I type

Tags: gnome, touchpad, themes, cursor, gnome-tweak-tool

My cursor keeps on jumping while I type, This happened all of a sudden. It was working fine but after I updated Ubuntu, then all this started. Even while I am typing this answer I am facing this problem, I am serious. I tried resetting the sensitivity and have locked already these are the settings for mouse and  touchpad:
[image]

I have also installed tweaks and these are my settings in tweak:

[image]

I also read somewhere resetting the cursor theme back to adwaita will do the job, but I can not find adwaita in cursor theme.

I am fairly new on Ubuntu, and when I installed it. I tried a lot of themes and deleted some of them again. I think due to that I might have deleted some important folders, but all thing rest is just working fine. I am not able to get what really the problem is. I wish to reset ubuntu to its initial stage, again getting important folders if I have deleted any. Is there a way. My laptop only has Ubuntu, as an operating system

The `xinput` results into this:

```
nerdrishabh@nerdrishabh-Vostro-15-3568:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3253-001                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
nerdrishabh@nerdrishabh-Vostro-15-3568:~$
```

The output for xinput list-props 16 is:

```
nerdrishabh@nerdrishabh-Vostro-15-3568:~$ xinput list-props 16
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (273): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (274):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (275):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (276):    23.851589
    Synaptics Edges (300):  1585, 5357, 1445, 4407
    Synaptics Finger (301): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (302):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (303):   245
    Synaptics Tap Durations (304):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (305):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (306):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (307):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (308):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (309): -111, 111
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (310): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (311):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (312): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.035868, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (313):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (314):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (315):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (316): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (317):   1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (318): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (319):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (320): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (321):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (322): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (323):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (324): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (325):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (326): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (327):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (328):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (329):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (330):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (331): 44, 42
    Synaptics Area (332):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (333):  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (334): 27, 27
    Device Product ID (266):    2, 7
    Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event6"
```

Previously I had a problem with smooth working of the touchpad, then I had to install synaptics, so i had updated ubuntu before installing it. After I installed it, the problem has arrived, i guess.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Now please add output of `xinput list-props 16`. And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu version is 18.04.2

Comment: can you please explain, how you are analysing things. So that in future if I run into a problem, I won't need to ask on this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `synaptics`. It has a very poor palm protection.
Remove it with

```
sudo apt remove 'xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.*'
```

`libinput` will control the touchpad with much better palm protection.

Comment: how do i install libinput, is the code sudo apt-get install libinput.

Comment: `libinput` should be there already.

Comment: I think the problem still persists, I tried in a new tab typing youtube and it, on its own clicked on Github bookmark and opened it.

Comment: You need to reboot. Then check if `libinput` is in use.

Comment: oh, thanks. how did you come to the conclusion that Synaptics is at guilt? What in the output did you saw that made you believe this?

Comment: I had this problem too ;-) And I saw that synaptics was in use from your output.

Comment: Last question, I previously had rough touchpad, and in order to solve it  I installed it. So will that roughness persist?

Comment: I don't know what roughness is. Maybe lack of inertia. You can ask a new question in this regard.

Comment: This reduced the problem but didn't eliminate it. I still face cursor-jumps, fewer, but it still occurs

Comment: There is nothing that can be done further. Try to hold your hands a different way while typing. Is `libinput` in use. Did you check it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks, for your help.